# Find $\tan(\alpha/2)$ given $\cos\alpha=-3/5$, where $\pi<\alpha<3\pi/2$

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

What would be folks' favorite way of finding $\tan(\alpha/2)$, given $\cos\alpha=-3/5$, where $\pi<\alpha<3\pi/2$?

Comment: Didn't see your other question before I wrote my answer, but couldn't you have used the help you got there to solve this one...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[Tan[a/2] /. Solve[Cos[a] == -3/5 && Pi <= a <= 3 Pi/2, a]]
```

*Mathematica* does all the work, I don't need to use my brain :p

Comment: Great answer! I will find it quite useful in class tonight. Thanks.